# Windows IoT Core and HttpClient on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: uwp, httpclient, iot

Does anyone know how to successfully make a http post to a web api rest service from a Universal Windows app running on a Raspberry Pi on Windows IOT Core?

It seems to always raise a exception saying "A connection could not be made to the server". I have enabled all the relevant setting in the appmanifest with no luck. Or.. better still simple being able to copy a file to a NAS.

There are ton's of examples loading images to Azure, which work just fine.

Comment: Sounds like it could be more of an IP or server issue. Have you tried using Postman in chrome to call the rest api outside of the Raspberry PI?